# Loop in C gone wrong

Tags: c, arrays, loops, variables

I have this code

```
for (i = 0; i < s; i++) // for i from 0 to Runners
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) //for j from 0 to laps
    {
        printf("\nEnter the time of lap %d for runner %d in minutes: ", j+1, i+1); // prompt for time for each runner in minutes
        while (scanf("%d", &Runnerm[i][j]) != 1) // While scanf returns not equal to 1 (value parsed == TRUE)
        {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') putchar(ch); // check if ch=character, compare last entry (\n if character)
            printf(" is not an integer.\nPlease enter only an "); // print error
            printf("integer, such as 1, 5, or 9 : \n"); // cnt print error
        }

        printf("Enter the time of lap %d for runner %d in seconds: ", j+1, i+1); //prompt for time for each runner in seconds
        while (scanf("%d", &Runners[i][j]) != 1) // While scanf returns not equal to 1 (value parsed == TRUE)
        {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') putchar(ch); // check if ch=character, compare last entry (\n if character)
            printf(" is not an integer.\nPlease enter only an "); // print error
            printf("integer, such as 1, 5, or 9 : \n"); // cnt print error
        }

        printf(" \n check 1 \n ");
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][j], Runners[i][j]); // Correct Check!

        printf(" \n check 1.5 \n ");
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][0], Runners[i][0]); // Incorrect Check!
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][1], Runners[i][1]); // Incorrect Check!
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][2], Runners[i][2]); // Incorrect Check!
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][3], Runners[i][3]); // Incorrect Check!

    }
}
```

The problem is, when check 1.5 runs the second time, `Runnerm[i][j]` gets values from `Runners[i+1][j]`

In short, when i changes value, the previous stored value of `Runnerm` will get the value of the Runners that is currently being stored..

Why is that? I can't find the reason..

**Edit:** The "check 1" and "check 1.5" exist for the whole purpose of -checking- the values at any given time of the loop. SO, even if I delete them, the program will still be broken.
ALSO when this is all fixed, the checks will be deleted, because I won't need to check the values any more. Thank you all for answering but I don't get why you suggest to do something with the checks, they are there for debugging. :\

**Edit** Found what caused the problem, when I used another version of the program that used fewer arrays, the problem was solved, when I started adding random un-used arrays, the problem appears.
Why is that? (New problem)
Could it be that the memory overlaps to the one that Runners[i][j] use?

Comment: How are the arrays defined?

Comment: int Runnerm[s][4]; //Runners / minutes
int Runners[s][4]; //Runners / seconds

Comment: You're saying that from `check 1` to `check 1.5`, `i` changes values, that is, it is incremented by `1`?

Comment: What are you trying to see in your `check 1.5`? You'll be outputting a lot of unassigned values (e.g. `Runnerm[i][1]` when j = 0)

Comment: yes, because I declare in the first loop i++
Check 1.5 runs perfectly the 1st time, from the 2nd time onwards (when i changes value) the whole thing breaks, and the values of and previous Runnerm get changed to the current values of Runners

Comment: The checks are made to see where and why the values get scrambled up, when I fix it, the checks will be deleted

Comment: Could this be a scanf / input buffering issue?  I hate scanf...

Comment: You really need to refactor the input error message into its own function (among other things).

Comment: I don't even know how to use anything except scanf, or what AJMansfield wants to say :P
I am not a programmer, I don't know anything except for the extreme basics of C, and most of the stuff, I know by fiddling with it the last 4 days

Comment: Could it be that you're hard-coding the second index (e.g. `Runnerm[i][0]`)?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your `printf` statement is showing the next runner/next time, but recording for the runner/time before:

```
printf("\nEnter the time of lap %d for runner %d in minutes: ", j+1, i+1);
                                                                ^^^^ ^^^^
```

Why not `i` `j`

Comment: Nice catch.  Love those base 0 to base 1 problem :)

Comment: Happens to us all :-)

Comment: because I want the user to see runner 1 and not runner 0.
that's not changing anything in the data. the basic user will be confused, seeing runner 99 as max, when the input was about 100 runners.

Answer (score 1):

Move these lines of code:

```
printf(" \n check 1.5 \n ");
printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][0], Runners[i][0]);
printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][1], Runners[i][1]);
printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][2], Runners[i][2]);
printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][3], Runners[i][3]);
```

to **outside** the `j` loop, remove the redundant prompt, and get rid of the magic constants used as loop bounds.

```
#define RUNNERS s
#define LAPS 4

for (i = 0; i < RUNNERS; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < LAPS; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter the time of lap %d for runner %d in seconds: ", j+1, i+1)
        while (scanf("%d", &Runners[i][j]) != 1)
        {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') putchar(ch);
            printf(" is not an integer.\nPlease enter only an integer, such as 1, 5, or 9 : \n");
        }

        printf(" \n check 1 \n ");
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][j], Runners[i][j]);

    }

    printf(" \n check 1.5 \n ");

    for (j = 0; j < LAPS; j++)
        printf("\n %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][j], Runners[i][j]);
}
```

Although personally, I think that nonfunctionality is the least of your problems: your code is overcommented and soaking [WET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions), and your output has way too many line breaks in it.

Comment: The checks ARE NOT THE PROBLEM, how many times do I have to say this? the checks exist to CHECK the values, even without the check 1 or the check 1.5, the values STILL CHANGE :O

Answer (score 1):

Fleshed-out the question code to an actual program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  int s = 3;
  int i;
  int j;
  int ch;
  int Runnerm[s][4]; //Runners / minutes
  int Runners[s][4]; //Runners / seconds

  for (i = 0; i < s; i++) // for i from 0 to Runners
     {
     for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) //for j from 0 to laps
        {
        printf("\nEnter the time of lap %d for runner %d in minutes: ", j+1, i+1); // prompt for time for each runner in minutes
        while (scanf("%d", &Runnerm[i][j]) != 1) // While scanf returns not equal to 1 (value parsed == TRUE)
           {
           while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') putchar(ch); // check if ch=character, compare last entry (\n if character)
           printf(" is not an integer.\nPlease enter only an "); // print error
           printf("integer, such as 1, 5, or 9 : \n"); // cnt print error
           }

        printf("Enter the time of lap %d for runner %d in seconds: ", j+1, i+1); //prompt for time for each runner in seconds
        while (scanf("%d", &Runners[i][j]) != 1) // While scanf returns not equal to 1 (value parsed == TRUE)
           {
           while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') putchar(ch); // check if ch=character, compare last entry (\n if character)
           printf(" is not an integer.\nPlease enter only an "); // print error
           printf("integer, such as 1, 5, or 9 : \n"); // cnt print error
           }

        printf("check 1 \n ");
        printf("\t %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][j], Runners[i][j]); // Correct Check!

        printf("check 1.5 \n ");
        printf("\t %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][0], Runners[i][0]); // Incorrect Check!
```

Added the following `if(j > ...` in order to not print uninitialized array values:

```
        if(j > 0) printf("\t %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][1], Runners[i][1]); // Incorrect Check!
        if(j > 1) printf("\t %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][2], Runners[i][2]); // Incorrect Check!
        if(j > 2) printf("\t %d minutes -- %d seconds \n", Runnerm[i][3], Runners[i][3]); // Incorrect Check!
        }
     }

  return(0);
  }
```

Then I compiled the code:

```
SLES11SP2:~/SO> gcc -Wall -o test *.c
```

And ran the code:

```
SLES11SP2:~/SO> ./test

Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 1 in minutes: 1
Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 1 in seconds: 2
check 1
   1 minutes -- 2 seconds
check 1.5
   1 minutes -- 2 seconds

Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 1 in minutes: 3
Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 1 in seconds: 4
check 1
   3 minutes -- 4 seconds
check 1.5
   1 minutes -- 2 seconds
   3 minutes -- 4 seconds

Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 1 in minutes: 5
Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 1 in seconds: 6
check 1
   5 minutes -- 6 seconds
check 1.5
   1 minutes -- 2 seconds
   3 minutes -- 4 seconds
   5 minutes -- 6 seconds

Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 1 in minutes: 7
Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 1 in seconds: 8
check 1
   7 minutes -- 8 seconds
check 1.5
   1 minutes -- 2 seconds
   3 minutes -- 4 seconds
   5 minutes -- 6 seconds
   7 minutes -- 8 seconds

Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 2 in minutes: 9
Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 2 in seconds: 10
check 1
   9 minutes -- 10 seconds
check 1.5
   9 minutes -- 10 seconds

Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 2 in minutes: 11
Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 2 in seconds: 12
check 1
   11 minutes -- 12 seconds
check 1.5
   9 minutes -- 10 seconds
   11 minutes -- 12 seconds

Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 2 in minutes: 13
Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 2 in seconds: 14
check 1
   13 minutes -- 14 seconds
check 1.5
   9 minutes -- 10 seconds
   11 minutes -- 12 seconds
   13 minutes -- 14 seconds

Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 2 in minutes: 15
Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 2 in seconds: 16
check 1
   15 minutes -- 16 seconds
check 1.5
   9 minutes -- 10 seconds
   11 minutes -- 12 seconds
   13 minutes -- 14 seconds
   15 minutes -- 16 seconds

Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 3 in minutes: 17
Enter the time of lap 1 for runner 3 in seconds: 18
check 1
   17 minutes -- 18 seconds
check 1.5
   17 minutes -- 18 seconds

Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 3 in minutes: 19
Enter the time of lap 2 for runner 3 in seconds: 20
check 1
   19 minutes -- 20 seconds
check 1.5
   17 minutes -- 18 seconds
   19 minutes -- 20 seconds

Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 3 in minutes: 21
Enter the time of lap 3 for runner 3 in seconds: 22
check 1
   21 minutes -- 22 seconds
check 1.5
   17 minutes -- 18 seconds
   19 minutes -- 20 seconds
   21 minutes -- 22 seconds

Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 3 in minutes: 23
Enter the time of lap 4 for runner 3 in seconds: 24
check 1
   23 minutes -- 24 seconds
check 1.5
   17 minutes -- 18 seconds
   19 minutes -- 20 seconds
   21 minutes -- 22 seconds
   23 minutes -- 24 seconds
SLES11SP2:~/SO>
```

It seem to work fine.

Comment: can you do it for two runners and see if it runs the same? because the problem appears only when there are more than 2 runners

Comment: There you go... 3 runners.

Comment: But I get the same wrong results, I have copy pasted your code into eclipse and still, runnerm changes :\

Comment: Found the problem, when I used a previous backup that works, and start adding random arrays, the problem appears, so I need to see why adding random arrays crashed the program, even when the arrays are un-used